# Handling regression for large unsorted datasets

Tags: java, csv, data-structures, data-storage

I am tackling a way to solve this problem. Two data sets (CSVs) as of different times or from different environments are to be compared, and their difference is to be calculated and reported.

There is an identifying key-column for these data sets, which should ideally matching columns on that key. These sets may not necessarily have the same number of records, in which case missing data would not have a reported difference. The data types are all either strings or floating point numbers.

For two files of size 300MB, with approximately 500,000 records each, what data structure or method of reading in data would be ideal without depleting heap memory? This is given that the records will not come in sorted order by the identifying key. Storing a map of

> **{key->Map{attribute->[valFile1,valFile2]}}** was my first instinct, but this proved largely inefficient.

Comment: Databases are very good for this type of thing

Comment: `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>` or replace `String` with `Float`. Two sets of data 300 MBs each should fit into memory even with overhead for `Map` internal structure

Comment: The simplest solution is to sort the data and then run a standard merge algorithm. The GNU `sort` utility makes quick work of the first, and the second is a trivial bit of code.